# Vue and bootstrap drop down select option populated from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need a way to handle both undefined and null

This is the bootstap template and data is coming from an array called dataPlus which is an array of objects from Firestore

-- Select a level --

```
      <b-form-select-option
        v-for="(item, index) of $myDb.cart.levels"
        :key="index"
        :value="item.level"
        >{{ item.level }}
      </b-form-select-option>
    </b-form-select>
  </div>
```

I need the b-form-select-option to display for either undefined OR null as the data from firestore can be either

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean？

```js
<b-form-select-option
  v-for="(item, index) of $myDb.cart.levels"
  :key="index"
  :value="handleToString(item.level)"
>
  {{ handleToString(item.level) }}
</b-form-select-option>
```

```js
handleToString (val) {
  return ['string', 'number'].includes(typeof val) ? val : (JSON.stringify(val) + '')
}
```